# disabling dates in the past bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Please give me the easiest way to disabling dates in the past bootstrap

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  $(function(){
    $('.datepicker').datepicker();
  });
</script>

Date: <input type="text" class="datepicker"></input>
```

I have included bootstrap datepicker.css, bootstrap-datepicker.js, bootstrap.min.css and jquery-1.11.1.js files

Comment: Use startDate attribute ? http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#startdate.

Comment: Try reading what the library has to say about it
http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Answer (score 0):

Use the `startDate` option.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('.datepicker').datepicker({
            startDate: new Date(),
        });
    });
</script>
```

Or you can simply use '+0d'

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('.datepicker').datepicker({
            startDate: '+0d',
        });
    });
</script>
```

This will start the calender from +0 days(i.e today)